# How do I check the number of Activitys of a third party android application?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

I want to check if WhatsApp creates separate activity for each conversation. I want to get an idea because I am creating a somewhat similar app.

(given that I am using a rooted device)

Answer (score 1):

Most probably not . Why would they create separate activity for each conversation ?

But still if you want you can check in this chat app - Telegram , it's similar to whatsapp and it is open source-

[Github repo](https://github.com/DrKLO/Telegram)